# What's the most efficient: a reference to an ArrayBase or an ArrayView?

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I'm doing improvement on a Rust codebase that uses the `ndarray` crate to manipulate arrays. I have one question I could not find an explicit answer in the documentation.

Is it more efficient to pass an instance of `ArrayView` as an argument to a function or should I use a reference to an `Array` instead? My intuition is that since `ArrayView` is a view of an array, when doing computations, it only passes a view of the array and does not grant ownership to the function (hence does not copy) the underlying data.

In short, is there any speed gain to expect from switching from passing instances of `ArrayView` to passing references of `Array`?

My goal is to avoid useless memory allocation/duplication which can be very costly when dealing with large arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ArrayBase` is a generic struct that can act as both an `ArrayView` and an `Array`, so I assume you mean a reference to the owned data, i.e. an `Array`.

Neither version will clone the array, so they should be approximately equally efficient. You can always benchmark to verify this.

As I see it, the difference is mostly that `ArrayView` will make the function more flexible – you can pass in parts of larger arrays, or an `ArrayView` created from a slice, whereas the variant that takes a reference to `Array` can only be called when you really have an `Array` of the desired size.